# ISNUMBER FIND - values from array

Tags: arrays, excel, search, find

I have the following function for a lookup.

```
=XLOOKUP(1,ISNUMBER(FIND(G2,DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44))*(ISNUMBER(FIND(D2,DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44)))*(ISNUMBER(FIND(include!$A$1,DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44)))*(MMULT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(TRANSPOSE(exclude!$A$1:$A$8),DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(exclude!$A$1:$A$8)))=0),DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44,"no match",2)
```

I need to change the segment

```
*(ISNUMBER(FIND(include!$A$1,DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44)))
```

Such that instead of using the value from include!$A$1, it uses one of the values from **include!A$1:$A$4**

Sample Data:

DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44 = Mypath/Info/speed/Data(531), Mypath/OtherInfo/distance/OtherData(532), or similar

OtherSheet!$A$1:$A$4 = distance, speed, pressure, temperature

The data set in DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44 will contain one of the terms from OtherSheet!$A$1:$A$4, so I need to evaluate each of the terms for a match. Just not sure how to format the function to do so.

Comment: Post few sample data then expected output.

Comment: how are you going to choose "one of the values" in OtherSheet ? Why not apply xlookup(0 or vlookup()? you have it working already so repeat it.

Comment: @Solar-Mike my data set has rows - some of them will contain text that matches one of four strings. The OtherSheet!$A1:$A4 contains the four words that I want to search against. I can make the code work when I reference e.g. OtherSheet!$A$1 but I do not know how to format the function such that it evaluates against each of the four terms in OtherSheet.

Comment: @Harun24hr see edits

Comment: @Solar-Mike see edits